# ¿Cómo se llama la parte verde que une los tomates?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Me surge la duda sobre cómo se llama la parte verde que une los tomates.

[image]

Por un lado me viene a la cabeza "sarmiento"

> [Sarmiento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XJj4TUo)
>
> Vástago de la vid, largo, delgado, flexible y nudoso, de donde brotan las hojas, las tijeretas y los racimos.

que de paso enlaza a [tijereta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zk1AQoy), y de ahí a [zarcillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cP1vXol%7CcP6or0l)

> Cada uno de los órganos largos, delgados y volubles que tienen ciertas plantas y que sirven a estas para asirse a tallos u otros objetos próximos, y que pueden ser de naturaleza caulinar, como en la vid, o foliácea, como en la calabacera y en el guisante.

¿Es simplemente un [tallo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z0soxHp)?

> Órgano de las plantas que se prolonga en sentido contrario al de la raíz y sirve de sustentáculo a las hojas, flores y frutos.

No estoy seguro de si la definición de "sarmiento" aplica, ya que esto no es una vid y no nos referimos a los tomates por "racimos" (¿o sí?). Zarcillo parece aplicar, pero no sé si se refiere a apéndices adicionales (es decir, tallitos más pequeños y delgados que el principal y que tienen la finalidad [solo] de asirse a otras cosas, no de mantener juntas o conectar parte de la planta [que es lo que haría un tallo principal]).

¿Cómo se llama a esa parte verde que une los tomates unos con otros?

Comment: ¿Y rama simplemente? Cuando los venden así unidos se les llama "tomate en rama". Aunque es posible que tenga un nombre más específico

Comment: Gracias a ambos por las respuestas (en forma de comentarios), pero creo que esta pregunta da para escribir una respuesta (como post, no como comentario) explicando, si es _rama_, porqué (frente a otras opciones que también parecen cuadrar, como _tallo_ o _sarmiento_). He añadido el tag [tag:selección-de-palabras], ya que lo que busco es saber cuál es la mejor opción, o la correcta, entre todas esas posibilidades. Gracias.

Comment: mmm...interesante...nunca había visto tomates unidos. Aquí siempre los venden separados. El desperdicio verde se queda en el lugar donde los cultivaron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que une los tomates es una rama de la planta, que es una ramificación (perdónese la redundancia) del tallo principal. Hay cierta ambigüedad en los términos pero en el uso común se suele hablar de *tallo* para referirse al tallo principal (el que crece hacia arriba desde la raíz, que en un árbol o arbusto leñoso se denomina *tronco*) y de *rama* para referirse a los tallos secundarios que surgen del principal (generalmente hacia los lados y a partir de nudos). Este uso de *rama* es el que aplica en el caso de los "tomates en rama".

Un sarmiento es término específico para una rama de la vid. Supongo que podría hacerse extensivo a otras plantas similares, pero no es formalmente correcto para el caso de la tomatera. Un zarcillo es una forma modificada de un tallo, una flor o un pecíolo (la estructura que une una rama con una hoja), es decir, no es un órgano claramente definido; es lo que usan las plantas trepadoras para enroscarse, usando un sistema de crecimiento diferenciado para "girar" en torno a lo que tocan.

Comment: Interestingly tomatoes sold still joined are usually labelled vine-ripened in English supermarkets so i can see why people might suggest _sarmiento_

Answer (score 4):

El tallo de una hoja, fruto o flor por el cual se une al tallo de la planta se llama **pedúnculo**;

En el DRAE:

> **[Pedúnculo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SKHBrlj)**
>
> 1. m. Bot. Pezón de la hoja, flor o fruto.

En Wikipedia:

> **[Pedúnculo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ped%C3%BAnculo)**
>
> En botánica se llama pedúnculo (...) al rabillo que sostiene un capítulo o una inflorescencia unifloral y, posteriormente a su fecundación, su fruto. En dicho caso, es entonces una mera prolongación del tallo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más correcto es llamarlo tallo.
En otro tiempo cuando compraba tomates, los pedía con rabo, porque suponía que se conservaban mejor. Me di cuenta de que no era lo correcto, cuando compré en una pequeña tienda de un paquistaní. Persona con bastantes años viviendo en España. Su expresión afable, se tornó sería. Comprendí que él lo estaba traduciendo de otra forma.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25531)